# How to style Material-UI v1 TextField similar to the v0 TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In material-UI v0 TextField can style properly with given attributes.
Just like this;

```
<TextField
     floatingLabelText="New Password"
     fullWidth={true}
     underlineStyle={styles.dialogInputUnderlineStyle}
     underlineFocusStyle={styles.dialogInputUnderlineFocusStyle}
     errorStyle={styles.dialogInputErrorStyle}
     floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.dialogInputLabelFocus}
     floatingLabelStyle={styles.dialogInputLabel}
     inputStyle={styles.dialogInputStyle}
     style={styles.rootStyle}
     hintText="Must be atleast 8 characters long"
     hintStyle={styles.dialogInputHintStyle}
     type="password"
     />
```

How to use below style attributes in Material-Ui v1?

```
   underlineStyle,
   underlineFocusStyle,
   errorStyle,
   floatingLabelFocusStyle,
   floatingLabelStyle.
   inputStyle,
   hintStyle
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to acces for Input Label you can use the **InputLabelProps** and for Input (underline and etc.) you can use **InputProps** and for helper text you can use **FormHelperTextProps**.

here is an example:

```
  <TextField
    defaultValue="react-bootstrap"
    label="Bootstrap"
    id="bootstrap-input"
    InputProps={{
      disableUnderline: true,
      classes: {
        root: classes.root,
        input: classes.input,
      },
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
      className: classes.label,
    }}
    FormHelperTextProps={{
      classes:{
        root: classes.yourCSS,
        error: classes.yourErrorCSS
      }
    }}
  />
```

here you should pass these styles for the component using **WithStyles**
in **material-ui**

please refer the API from here: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: I already go through the API documentation. But I couldn't understand. Can you give a simple example with classes?